# Custom Deserialization of JSON FIELD with Jackson in java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given a simple entity class like this

```
public class User
{
  @JsonProperty
  public Calendar createdOn;

  @JsonProperty
  public String name;
}
```

Is there a way for me to hook into the jackson streaming API to custom deserialize ONLY the createdOn field?  If there's not, then would something like this be possible in the future?

```
public class User
{
  @JsonProperty
  @JsonConverter(MyCustomCalendarConverter.class)
  public Calendar createdOn;

  @JsonProperty
  public String name;
}
```

It appears that I could [custom deserialize the entire entity](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers).  I'm just curious if there is a way to customize the deserialization just a field at a time in order to, for example, custom parse a particular date format, or read an array of values into a custom entity, etc. while letting Jackson deserialize the rest of the entity normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define custom serialize a specific field using @JsonSerialize:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=MuCustomCalendarConverter.class)
```

Comment: Thanks!   (Sorry I missed this in the docs... I had been looking at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers)

Comment: Hmm... anything special I need to do with the ObjectMapper for it to use this?   I've created a class that extends DateDeserializer and applied it to my property (of type java.util.Date) and just created a breakpoint in the constructor.   When I deserialize the breakpoint is never hit and I get a deserialization error (which is why I want to customize the deserialization...)   Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I ended up switching to extending from `FromStringDeserializer<Date>` and that did the trick... but I'm also deploying to GAE and seemed to have had the same trouble with adding a custom serializer until I did a clean/rebuild on my project... probably had nothing to do with Jackson after all.

Comment: No, nothing special should be needed to enable it. GAE might cause some issues, with respect to instantiating that class; whether due to recognizing annotations, or by use of Class.newInstance(). If you could pin it down, a bug report could help, in case other devs with GAE systems might be able to help

Comment: If I pin down anything reproducible I'll get a bug filed.  In the meantime I've got this working.   Thanks again for all the help and for a great JSON library!