# date pass to json

Tags: java, jquery, json

I use jQuery DataTable and I have field in class:

```
public class Test {
private Date date;
...
}
```

I want pass to JavaScript object Test, but date as dd.mm.yyyy. I have in filed by miliseconds.
How Can I do that? I use JSON

Comment: I would recommend passing the date as a Unix timestamp to the UI, and convert it to a date object once you receive it.

Comment: I tried to understand your query. But its not clear to me. Can post what is the expected output and what is your actual output?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what JSON API you use for serializing your Test class. Anyhow, I believe all APIs have the ability to apply custom formatter/converter at field level. In this formatter/converter you can convert your java `Date` object to `String` of required format.

For example [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) (my favorite JSON API) provides the Converter that you can implement. Check the example [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html)  (refer to **Date Converter** section).

If you use Jackson you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5269988/579580) and [this example](http://loianegroner.com/2010/09/how-to-serialize-java-util-date-with-jackson-json-processor-spring-3-0/).

There are many other JSON APIs (JAXB etc), but IMO XStream is the easier to start with.

Comment: I use Jackson, but when i add import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect; i have error: The import org.codehaus cannot be 
  resolved why?

Comment: that means that you miss the jar on you compile/build path. Do you work with Eclipse?

Comment: do you use maven? if yes, check that jackson appears in dependency list in your pom.xml, otherwise check your project build path (right click your project root in package explorer view, select Build Path -> Configure Build Path, go to Libraries tab and add jackson jar )