# Can Jackson deal with intermediate relationships

Tags: java, json, jackson

Let's say I have a parent child relationship.  My Parent json looks like

```
{
   childrens: [...]
}
```

Let's say the model I want to (de)serialize to/from has an intermediate object between the parent and children.

```
class Parent {
   Intermediate intermediate
}

class Intermediate {
   Child[] children;
}
```

Can I configure Jackson to create that intermediate object when deserializing the json into the model, and similarly skip the intermediate object when serializing back to json?

Comment: I don't believe this can be done without writing a [custom deserializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) (and serializer) for Parent.

Comment: @rmlan If the model in my question was really in the middle of a much larger model tree, would the custom deserializer need to deal with everything else in that model tree?  Or can I limit it so I only need to write custom code around Parent/Intermediate/Child?

Comment: You should be able to use the @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class) (and @JsonSerialize) annotations on the field itself without having to handle the whole object. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269637/custom-deserialization-of-json-field-with-jackson-in-java)

Comment: I didn't know about JsonUnwrapped. Based on the docs, that should actually do the trick.

Comment: From what I see @JsonUnwrapped does not apply to lists.

Comment: I just did a small test and it worked just fine with the structure you describe.

Comment: @rmlan can you add your test as an answer and I will accept?  Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@JsonUnwrapped`annotation for this case. Here is an example with a similar structure to your post

**Parent.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonUnwrapped;

public class Parent {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Intermediate intermediate;

    public Intermediate getIntermediate() {
        return intermediate;
    }

    public void setIntermediate(Intermediate intermediate) {
        this.intermediate = intermediate;
    }
}
```

**Intermediate.java**

```
public class Intermediate {
    private Child[] children;

    public Child[] getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Child[] children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

**Child.java**

```
public class Child {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**Example document**

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Foo",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "Bar",
      "age": 22
    }
  ]  
}
```

**Test Driver**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Parent parent = mapper.readValue(json, Parent.class);

for (Child child : parent.getIntermediate().getChildren()) {
    System.out.println("Child: " + child.getName() + " is " + child.getAge() + " years old.");
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Child: Foo is 20 years old.
Child: Bar is 22 years old.
```